# Block a program launched from batch file from launching another program

Tags: windows, batch-file, shell-script

I am trying to work around a limitation. I'll give the full context, just for completeness.

In Unreal Engine, each Unreal project (a .uproject file) is associated with a specific version or a specific installation of the engine/editor. When launching the project by double-clicking it, it runs:

```
UnrealVersionSelector.exe /editor "C:\path\to\myproject.uproject"
```

Which in turn launches the associated engine editor. UnrealVersionSelector is in charge of parsing the .uproject file, finding the correct engine, and launching the editor.

What I need in my batch file is **just the location of the engine**. I want to run some other utility within that folder. Unfortunately, there is no option to just print the location of the engine. UnrealVersionSelector's source code is public and can be found here: https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/release/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealVersionSelector/Private/UnrealVersionSelector.cpp

My current plan: make the batch file launch UnrealVersionSelector in a special way that blocks it from actually launching the editor - then use the path of the failed editor launch to get the information I want.

Is this possible from a batch file?

Obviously I'm all ears for a better approach or something obvious that I'm missing.

Comment: if you open a cmd window and type UnrealVersionSelector.exe /? does it display any switches?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It just says invalid command line - which is expected if you just take a look at the source code (linked within the question). It's a good idea most of the time though! Right now I'm assuming this is impossible/not worth the effort, and just writing custom code to figure out the path I need by myself, basically reimplementing the code I was trying to leverage.

Comment: Its a dead link.

Comment: Oh, I forgot you had to register with them and link your GitHub account in order to see it... My bad.

Answer (score 1):

The engine is stored in the field "Engine Association" in the project file. If it is not an engine number, it can be a GUID for the engine build.

There is a "lookup  table" in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Epic Games/Unreal Engine/Builds` so you can line up a GUID with an engine build.

So if you can extract the GUID (see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943001/extracting-text-from-xml-file-via-batch-file), then do a `reg query`, you  probably have what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something similar to this, and in Python. It's annoyingly complex code, and there's ways to get it wrong, so it's frustrating that I can't use the definitive implementation in UnrealVersionSelector.